# Multiplication of two numbers time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, multiplication

So I have two base 10 int number with m digits and n digits. What should be the time complexity of m x n? I have done some lookups and saw that in background, the two numbers are converted into binary numbers and you add the sum of all product between each digit of one number with the other number. So will it be O(m x n) or O( numDigitsInBinaryOfNumberOne * numDigitsInBinaryOfNumberTwo) ?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52640/complexity-of-multiplication

Comment: There's an extensive chapter in Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming*: "How Fast Can We Multiply?"